# Android AlertDialog item selection

Tags: java, android, user-interface, interface, android-alertdialog

I have an GUI interface with the method `public Item selectItem(Item[] items);` which returns one of the items; I implemented this interface into my Activity and used an AlertDialog which lets the user select one Item. Here is my code:

```
private Item tempItem;

@Override
    public Item selectItem(final Item[] items) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Select an Item");
        builder.setItems(toStringArray(items), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int choice) {
                tempItem = items[choice];
            }

        });
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.show();
        return tempItem;
    }
```

`tempItem` is a support variable becuase I can't return the value inside the `onClick()` method. The problem is that the method returns `null` because `tempItem` is not jet set. Is there a better solution to implement this method using AlertDialog?

Comment: I tried adding `while(tempItem==null) {};` before the return statement but then the UI freezes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement a click listener for your class that allows you to use onClick as a class method and thus work with it's variables.

```
public class YourClass extends Whatever implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener{
    private item;
    private Item[] items;
    private AlertDialog.Builder builder1;
    private AlertDialog.Builder builder2;

    @Override
    public Item selectItem(final Item[] items) {
        this.items = items;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder1.setTitle("Select an Item");
        builder1.setItems(toStringArray(items), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(this));
        builder1.setCancelable(false);
        builder1.show();

        return item;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int choice){
        if(dialog.equals(builder1)
            item = items[choice];
        else if(dialog.equals(builder2))
            // do what you want for dialog 2
    }
}
```

Just an option, but it is how I have done it when I have had to do similar things in the past.

Comment: and if i have multiple dialogs, how can I see which one was clicked?

Comment: another problem with this solution is, that i can't access `items` in the `onClick` method...

Comment: @VoidCats sure you can, just create an items variable you can use throughout your class and set it in your selectItem class. something like this.items = items; You can then use your onClick variables to determine what is clicked, even from multiple dialogs. I will update my post when I get a second.

Comment: @VoidCats You may be right on the multiple dialog issue, I thought that the dialog variable passed contained some version of a unique identifier but I can't seem to find one.

Comment: @VoidCatz nevermind, I figured it out and edited my answer. Also, sorry for typing your name wrong in my responses